# Spotify Android SDK: Error while running the sample application

Tags: android, spotify, spotify-app

Spotify Android SDK offer two libraries - [App Remote](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/app-remote-lib/docs/) and [Authentication](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/auth-lib/docs/). There are sample application available on the github which is using these two libraries - [github - Spotify Sample Application](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk)

I have created two different android emulator with the below device configurations.

The sample application is running without any issues in the ***Pixel_4_API_28*** device.

***Device Specification:***

> 1. **Name:** Pixel_4_API_28
> 2. **CPU/ABI:** Google PlayStore Intel Atom (x86)
> 3. **Target:** google_apis_playstore [Google PlayStore] (API level 28)
> 4. **Skin:** pixel_4
> 5. **hw.device.name:** pixel_4
> 6. **hw.lcd.height:** 2280
> 7. **hw.lcd.width:** 1080
> 8. **hw.lcd.density:** 440
> 9. **PlayStore.enabled:** true
> 10. **image.sysdir.1:** system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\

However, I am receiving the error while running the same application in the ***Automotive Virtual Device***.

***Device Specification:***

> 1. **Name:** Automotive_Virtual_Device
> 2. **CPU/ABI:** Automotive Intel Atom (x86)
> 3. **Target:** android-automotive-playstore [Automotive] (API level 28)
> 4. **Skin:** 1080x1920
> 5. **hw.device.name:** automotive_1024p_landscape
> 6. **hw.lcd.height:** 1920
> 7. **hw.lcd.width:** 1080
> 8. **hw.lcd.density:** 190
> 9. **PlayStore.enabled:** true
> 10. **image.sysdir.1:** system-images\android-28\android-automotive-playstore\x86\

**Error Details:**

```
E/com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.webview.LoginDialog: Can't redirect due to mismatch. 
Request redirect-uri: com.example.khmusic://callback/
Response redirect-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=1046568431490-ij1gi5shcp2gtorls09frkc56d4mjbe2.apps.googleusercontent.com&state=AQB%2Bj3iIVPBTqhQ6rhcDkmzDsgoFbxzGrQXd%2Bm5jO8mG%2F9Otq%2F%2FYFMS5NJOS3HgHfBQDxP9BCdDYIJpGN7WPsWpe7imosodu%2BZWB%2Biopw7FelY%2F83J8QUF3gLp9EVEvG7p%2BVcgJOecJ6%2FatcihQ31HRiOjdOPPM7vZBF0HRpUcpPnMaoZ3Udv8fRWhjZa3qL5icJYQp%2BGIz4iJ%2BOsdXSbcgDi0Gl3sjvCzTAWxGlOuVer51IjAez%2Fyw0eNIx%2B0PX97nabbjPLDyxRRdtPOQyNlNuJii9%2B8nTv0au7uJxZKJ2apXuwex5uQccfr1bCoIPTXZtr7Ij8Wo5yukP4VRzPvwJqXgA3qNIIwIyBUbkeXvRfmIEhdu730FTvALHfQbXK%2FFVnLXX9NMkAmu9m5%2FBEzNTFy6RxgTaR1Ej6GiZY5aQOmJzGnqGaCmXcGM2NBFv%2B7JTqbLAm%2B9g%2Blr8ZVNRC47tsBtBtRB6ToIahgdGcEk79%2FjQaU9PQHjPJv88cRWAOlbNJJ%2BWCaB%2FhMj2fg3ZuTH1UcnVbLoTDi1InmNqm4HOb%2Bz4rrecFvqnOkCRYqu7m1akMChP%2FnhAB9reL0%2BklrONO7IExcuO1hGvciGItWGt%2B2eVGHOGy%2F4hqFrVfgMekZL63diWskYLf0q7g3b2EsG6UHRTQ4iT8u9QLUr4srIukufc3N%2B5t6g%2FpOj9ZXbbpHiLmMNmH3J0yvGgIzNrziNrh8DZquXhCWpgJpp31NvZSM%2F0FQsEcQP0uP8dPIF7XoUVbRW4DBPmy2ZBJT8EMgCr4XMUvkqCeS37rNGZTn9%2FvoyyjhOSlZiexPSFP02ipfhB4fOQSgSeBOX5aRff1YSy8uWZzg%3D%3D&scope=profile+email+openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fredirect E/Spotify Auth Client: Spotify auth Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't redirect due to mismatch. 
Request redirect-uri: com.example.khmusic://callback/
Response redirect-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=1046568431490-ij1gi5shcp2gtorls09frkc56d4mjbe2.apps.googleusercontent.com&state=AQB%2Bj3iIVPBTqhQ6rhcDkmzDsgoFbxzGrQXd%2Bm5jO8mG%2F9Otq%2F%2FYFMS5NJOS3HgHfBQDxP9BCdDYIJpGN7WPsWpe7imosodu%2BZWB%2Biopw7FelY%2F83J8QUF3gLp9EVEvG7p%2BVcgJOecJ6%2FatcihQ31HRiOjdOPPM7vZBF0HRpUcpPnMaoZ3Udv8fRWhjZa3qL5icJYQp%2BGIz4iJ%2BOsdXSbcgDi0Gl3sjvCzTAWxGlOuVer51IjAez%2Fyw0eNIx%2B0PX97nabbjPLDyxRRdtPOQyNlNuJii9%2B8nTv0au7uJxZKJ2apXuwex5uQccfr1bCoIPTXZtr7Ij8Wo5yukP4VRzPvwJqXgA3qNIIwIyBUbkeXvRfmIEhdu730FTvALHfQbXK%2FFVnLXX9NMkAmu9m5%2FBEzNTFy6RxgTaR1Ej6GiZY5aQOmJzGnqGaCmXcGM2NBFv%2B7JTqbLAm%2B9g%2Blr8ZVNRC47tsBtBtRB6ToIahgdGcEk79%2FjQaU9PQHjPJv88cRWAOlbNJJ%2BWCaB%2FhMj2fg3ZuTH1UcnVbLoTDi1InmNqm4HOb%2Bz4rrecFvqnOkCRYqu7m1akMChP%2FnhAB9reL0%2BklrONO7IExcuO1hGvciGItWGt%2B2eVGHOGy%2F4hqFrVfgMekZL63diWskYLf0q7g3b2EsG6UHRTQ4iT8u9QLUr4srIukufc3N%2B5t6g%2FpOj9ZXbbpHiLmMNmH3J0yvGgIzNrziNrh8DZquXhCWpgJpp31NvZSM%2F0FQsEcQP0uP8dPIF7XoUVbRW4DBPmy2ZBJT8EMgCr4XMUvkqCeS37rNGZTn9%2FvoyyjhOSlZiexPSFP02ipfhB4fOQSgSeBOX5aRff1YSy8uWZzg%3D%3D&scope=profile+email+openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fredirect
    at com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.webview.LoginDialog$2.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(LoginDialog.java:175)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewClient.java:83)
    at Cs.a(PG:1)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(PG:16)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6728)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Could someone please help fix/understand this error as I am receiving this error only on the ***Automotive_Virtual_Device***. Let me know if any further information are required.

Thank you in advance!